# No standard error output in quantile regression using R

Tags: r, regression, quantile

I am running a quantile regression (as my residuals in linear regression were not normally distributed) for a study on the association of mediterranean diet and inflammatory markers. As I was building the model I got outputs for beta coefficients and standard error plus p-values, and confidence intervals. However, once I stratified for low and high levels of exercise, there was no longer an output for standard error. Any ideas?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/77Oay.png)

Comment: I used to coding:summary(model_CRP_quantile_14) [then on next line] summary(model_CRP_quantile_14, se = "rank") which I used for the earlier models and got out puts with se and then conf ints. If I just run the first line by itself I also get coefficient and cons ints only - NO standard error???

Comment: You don't need to pipe into `filter`, there is an argument `rq(..., subset = exercise_level == "low")`.

Answer (score 1):

By default rq does not returns standard errors, but rather the confidence interval by inverting a rank test. If you want standard errors you have to specify another method for `se`, such as `se="boot"`.

Note: the whole point of quantile regression is to move away from means and SD, so this may not be the most adequate estimate for your problem.